# ManualResetEvent not working as expected in Mono

Tags: c#, sockets

I'm using a socket with tcp to send data to a remote server. I'm using a ManualResetEvent and System.Timers.Timer to facilitate the condition of not being able to connect to the remote host. Either the ConnectedCallback is called with a successful connection which will Set the ManualResetEvent or it can’t connect and it falls back to the timer which should, close the socket and tell the main thread to continue and handle not being connected.

The logic works fine because I tried it using a simple bool, I'm not sure if I’m using the ManualResetEvent object wrong?

I should also add, this a class library made for .NET Frameworks 4.6 and is in Mono
Code:

```
public void StartConnect()
{
    ConnectCue.Reset();
    // Retrieve server config
    var serverConfig = LocalConfig.GetConfig<VmeServerConfig>();

    var ipHostInfo = Dns.GetHostEntry(serverConfig.BaseAddress);
    var ipAddress = ipHostInfo.AddressList[0];

#if DEBUG
    var remoteEp = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Loopback, Port);
#else
    var remoteEp = new IPEndPoint(ipAddress, Port);
#endif

    // Create a TCP/IP socket.  
    TcpSocket = new Socket(ipAddress.AddressFamily,
        SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp)
    {
        ReceiveTimeout = serverConfig.Timeout * 1000,
        SendTimeout = serverConfig.Timeout * 1000
    };

    // Connect to the remote endpoint
    TcpSocket.BeginConnect(remoteEp,
        new AsyncCallback(ConnectedCallback), TcpSocket);


    // Timer that will signal main thread to continue
    var timeoutTimer = new System.Timers.Timer()
    {
        Interval = serverConfig.Timeout * 1000,
        AutoReset = false,
        Enabled = true
    };

    // Event to singal thread to continue if connection takes long
    timeoutTimer.Elapsed += delegate (object sender, ElapsedEventArgs args)
    {
        // Nothing to do here
        if (IsConnected)
            return;

#if DEBUG
    Interface.RootLogger.Write(LogType.Warning, "TICK: Not connected");       
#endif
        ConnectCue.Set();                
        TcpSocket.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
        TcpSocket.Close();
    };


    timeoutTimer.Start();

    // Cue the main thread
    ConnectCue.WaitOne();

    if (IsConnected) return;

    //Not connected, handle stuff...
}

/// <summary>
/// Invoked when a connection to the service has been made or not been made
/// </summary>
/// <param name="ar"></param>
private void ConnectedCallback(IAsyncResult ar)
{

    // Retrieve the socket from the state object.  
    var tcpSocket = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;


    // If we couldn't then its been handled by timeout
    if (!tcpSocket.Connected)
        return;

    try
    {
        //doing stuff..
    }
    catch (System.Exception)
    {
        tcpSocket.Close();
        throw;
    }

    // Signal the main thread that the connection has been made.  
    ConnectCue.Set();
}
```

Comment: I have two questions 1) Are you getting an exception in the Connection Callback?  2) Try with a 5 second timeout and see if it works.  One second may be too short.  You are only resetting the AutoReset once so for multiple connections you are not resetting.

Comment: @jdweng Thanks for the reply, The timeout prop is set to 10 seconds which is plenty of time. Additionally, this is the client and therefore only ever needs to connect once. I'm using the exact same logic for the server, only that it resets everytime a client connects like you suggested and it works fine, the server a is a widows console application on .net 4.6. To answer you second question, no i'm not getting an exception unless i try calling endrecieve and we couldn't connect

Comment: The code in the snippet never sets the IsConnected variable to true.